# Network proxy settings BQ Aquaris E4.5

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, proxy, phone

I am the proud owner of a brand new Ubuntu phone and have come across a basic problem right away.

How can I configure network proxy settings? I have poked around in the network settings, but have not found anything related. If there is no GUI, any way to set this up via console?

Comment: In case there are no system wide proxy settings like in Desktop Ubuntu, is there maybe a way to configure the browser with proxy settings, to start with? Thanks in advance, M.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the "Ubuntu phone" community on Launchpad (see [here](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg12637.html)), I was able to set my system proxy settings via the 'gsettings set' command (identically to the working settings on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop systems):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy use-same-proxy false
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode "'manual'"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy ignore-hosts "['localhost', '127.0.0.0/8', '192.168.0.0/16', '::1']"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp host "'192.168.112.1'"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp port 800
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks host "'192.168.112.1'"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.socks port 800
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host "'192.168.112.1'"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port 800
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http use-authentication false
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https host "'192.168.112.1'"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https port 800
```

Those proxy settings are currently not used by the browser app through and I have requested this feature accordingly (see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/webbrowser-app/+bug/1452291)).

Addition from 2015-05-07 (also documented here - sorry, I am not allowed to include another link, my reputation is too low):
I think I made the bowser app work with the proxy. I was actually trying
to enable command line apps like wget to work via proxy and added to
/etc/environment

```
http_proxy=http://192.168.112.1:800/
https_proxy=http://192.168.112.1:800/
ftp_proxy=http://192.168.112.1:800/
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.0.0/16"
HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.112.1:800/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.112.1:800/
FTP_PROXY=http://192.168.112.1:800/
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.0.0/16"
```

After that, I was able to run wget for the first time successfully:

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ wget www.spiegel.de
--2015-05-07 10:09:33--  http://www.spiegel.de/
Connecting to 192.168.112.1:800... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 233514 (228K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[======================================>] 233,514      400KB/s   in 0.6s  

2015-05-07 10:09:34 (400 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [233514/233514]
```

By coincidence, I found out that the browser app also seems to pick this
configuration up successfully and the browser started to work with the
proxy.

I have now three different types of proxy configurations on my phone:

1. via gsettings, see my earlier e-mails - not sure if this has
   currently an effect on any application
2. via /etc/environment for certain command line applications and
   seemingly the browser
3. via 95proxies in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ for apt

I am now testing if other apps actually up one of those configuration
types. "Shorts" (the RSS app) for example seems not to work still.

Addition from 2015-05-07:
Syncevolution is seemingly picking up the proxy information from type 2) as well. Quite important for me as I am using it to sync calendar and contact data with an owncloud server.

Comment: as of 11.2016 none of these settings work on Meizu Pro 5, at least for http in the system web browser. Unable to edit /etc/environment as it is read-only and non-remountable